# how can modify means write xml file save in the same resource folder in android

Tags: android, xml, file

i am implementing read and write xml in resource folder reading is ok how can modify this xml file save as same resource folder

i am using this code reading its working fine how can modify the xml file

```
EditText myXmlContent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_xml);
        String stringXmlContent;
        try {
            stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(this);
            myXmlContent.setText(stringXmlContent);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getEventsFromAnXML(Activity activity) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
    {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Resources res = activity.getResources();
        XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.nab);
        xpp.next();
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
            {
                stringBuffer.append("--- Start XML ---");
            }
            else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            {
                stringBuffer.append("\nSTART_TAG: "+xpp.getName());
            }
            else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
            {
                stringBuffer.append("\nEND_TAG: "+xpp.getName());
            }
            else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
            {
                stringBuffer.append("\nTEXT: "+xpp.getText());
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
        stringBuffer.append("\n--- End XML ---");
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

display reading purpose:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/my_xml"
    />
    <Button android:text="Write" 
          android:id="@+id/button1" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

how can modify the xml file save as resource folder or sdcard location forward some suggestion thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

res/ resources are read-only. You can save it as an internal file or in the sd card.

Comment: its ok i am saved in sdcrad how can write (modify) this xml file in android please forward some suggestion